# apply conditional numbering to grouped data in R

Tags: r, group-by, rank

I have a table like the one below with 100's of rows of data.

```
ID  RANK
1   2
1   3
1   3
2   4
2   8
3   3
3   3
3   3
4   6
4   7
4   7
4   7
4   7
4   7
4   6
```

I want to try to find a way to group the data by ID so that I can ReRank each group separately. 
 
  The ReRank column is based on the Rank column and basically renumbering it starting at 1 from least to greatest, but it's important to note that the the number in the ReRank column can be put in more than once depending on the numbers in the Rank column .

In other words, the output needs to look like this

```
ID   Rank ReRANK
1    3       2
1    2       1
1    3       2
2    4       1
2    8       2
3    3       1
3    3       1
3    3       1
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to be able to ReRank the the columns by the grouped columns and the value of the Rank columns.

This has been my best guess so far, but it definitely is not doing what I need it to do

```
ReRANK = mat.or.vec(length(RANK),1)
ReRANK[1] = counter = 1
for(i in 2:length(RANK)) {
  if (RANK[i] != RANK[i-1]) { counter = counter + 1 }
  ReRANK[i] = counter
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: I don't know why your output is ordered differently than the input, but in dplyr, you could try `group_by(df, ID) %>% mutate(ReRANK = dense_rank(Rank))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `ave` and `rank`:

```
df$ReRank <- ave(df$Rank, df$ID, FUN=function(i) rank(i, ties.method="min"))
```

The min argument in rank assures that the minimum ranking will occur when there are ties. the default is to take the mean of the ranks.

In the case that you have ties lower down in the groups, `rank` will count those lower values and then add continue with the next lowest value as the count of the lower values + 1. These values wil still be ordered and distinct. If you really want to have the count be 1, 2, 3, and so on rather than 1, 3, 6 or whatever depending on the number of duplicate values, here is a little hack using `factor`:

```
df$ReRank <- ave(df$Rank, df$ID, FUN=function(i) {
                 as.integer(factor(rank(i, ties.method="min"))))
```

Here, we use `factor` to build values counting from upward for each level. We then coerce it to be an integer.

For example,

```
temp <- c(rep(1, 3), 2,5,1,4,3,7)
[1] 2.5 2.5 2.5 5.0 8.0 2.5 7.0 6.0 9.0
rank(temp, ties.method="min")
[1] 1 1 1 5 8 1 7 6 9
as.integer(factor(rank(temp, ties.method="min")))
[1] 1 1 1 2 5 1 4 3 6
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID   Rank 
1    2       
1    3       
1    3       
2    4       
2    8       
3    3      
3    3       
3    3 ")
```